# Convertir a funciones lambda Java

Tags: java, lambda

Hola trato de mejorar mi código sustituyendo ciclos de for y while por funciones lambda (stream) he intentado mejorar este código pero me es imposible, se agrdece la ayuda.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < individuals.size() - 1; i++)
                for (int j = individuals.size() - 1; j > i; j--)
                    if (individuals.get(i).redundant(individuals.get(j)))
                        individuals.remove(j);
```

he intentado lo siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < individuals.size() - 1; i++)
   individuals.stream()
               .reverse()
               .filter(individuals.get(i).redundant(in))
               .remove();
```

pero no es correcto y se pasa de la condicion de parada.

Answer (score 0):

Si el método `redundant()` lo que hace es determinar si ambos objetos con iguales deberías implementar esa lógica en el método `equals()`.

Ahora, partiendo de la suposición anterior, hacer lo que quieres sería muy sencillo ya que la interfaz `Stream` proporciona un método para obtener solo aquellos elementos distintos ([`Stream#distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct())).

```
List sinDuplicados = individuals.stream().distinct().toList();
```

Este código creará una nueva lista sin elementos duplicados;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***NOTA:*** El método `Stream#toList()` está disponible a partir de Java 16. Anterior a esta versión debes usar un recolector para lograr lo mismo.

```
individuals.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```